# Django create new object based on current object type

Tags: python, django, types

I have a setup for a test with multiple question types (i.e., short answer, multiple choice). These tests can be created dynamically. What I am trying to do now is create a function to make the appropriate set of responses for a test. My models are set up like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    pass
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
class NumQ(Question):
    pass
class TextQ(Question):
    pass

class Response(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
class Answer(models.Model):
    pass
class NumA(Answer):
    question = models.ForeignKey(NumQ)
    answer = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
class TextA(Answer):
    question = models.ForeignKey(TextQ)
    answer = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I am making a function to create a Response, in which I loop through all of the Questions for the test and create new Answers. However, I want to create the correct type of answer. I figured out I can get the actual type of Question with [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager), but from this, the only way I can figure out how to create the right answer type is with a bunch of if/elif statements, which is really ugly (especially since there are a lot more than 2 question types).

The best alternative I can think of at this point would be adding an `answer_type` field to each question, but I am not sure how I would convert that field (either a `CharField` or a custom `TypeField`) into actually generating a new object, plus giving it the correct apparent type (`Answer`). I suppose I could use `eval`, but that seems like a really ugly solution. (In that case, I wouldn't even need the extra field; I could just replace the Q with A from the type.) But is there a better alternative to `eval` in this case?

Comment: Why would you need anything other than a `TextField`, even if the answer is numeric, since you receive all input from the user as text?

Comment: The TextQ and NumQ are just examples. I have more complicated question types like multiple choice, but for the sake of a simple example I just picked 2 question types with no other model dependencies.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to simply create a dictionary mapping a answer type name to its unbound class type, ex: {``'NumA':NumA,...}``. But this dictionary likely exists somewhere in the guts of Django. I can't seem to find it in the docs though.

Comment: Are you suggesting adding a dictionary are making use of an existing one? How exactly would this dictionary be used?

Comment: With your ``aswer_type`` field. You're essentially doing what you would do with an ``eval`` but protecting the input. However, why do you need to do this a all? Could you not simply create a ``ForeignKey`` into the ``Answer`` model from the ``Question`` model, which I assume is loaded polymorphically? I guess I don't understand in what situation a ``Question`` would be created without an ``Answer``, or where the type of that ``Answer`` would be known when making the ``Question`` but not the actual ``Answer``.

Comment: I just realized that I left out the `question` field for the answers in my example, which I corrected now. This might help some of the confusion. But this still doesn't solve the issue. 

The setup is that an admin creates a `Test` (writes the questions) and then the users submit `Response`s. (Each test would be associated with a user, but I left that out for simplicity.) So that's why you would have questions without answers. The answers (of the specific type) are generated when a user starts a response.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [django-typed-models](https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models) resolves your problem.

Ie. for `NumQ` you need to set `answer_type='appname.numa'`, and later on answers creating you simply pass `type=answer_type` to answer constructor.

Different approach: if you want to get model class form string, use function `get_model` from `django.db.models.loading`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AnswerType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answer = models.ManyToManyField(AnswerType)

class Result(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    reponse = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Attempts(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    taken_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    answer = models.ManyToMany(Result)

class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    results = models.ManyToManyField(Responses)
```

1. Question can have multiple answers (for multiple choice questions).
2. Each Quiz can have multiple questions.
3. For each attempt, the Student, Quiz and Answers are recorded.
4. A Result contains a link to the question, and the response entered for one quiz.
5. For each answer, you have a label (displayed on the form), a name (for your own reference) and a value (the key/weight/score for this answer) - this is normally used for weighted quizzes.

I think doing it like this keeps your models flexible enough.  Your only headache will be getting the forms correctly mapped out, I suggest you use FormWizard and create your own custom forms.

Comment: Why do you have so many of these fields as `ManyToManyField`s? Is there any advantage, because it doesn't seem necessary for some of those (just foreign key would suffice).

Also, how does this solve the problem of different answers? I would still have to have different `AnswerType` subclasses to accommodate the different types of questions.

Comment: ForeignKey would restrict one relationship, so whenever you want multiple relations you need manytomany. So one quiz - many questions and many results; one attempt per quiz, but each attempt has many answers; one question can one or more answers (multiple choice questions).

Comment: Not every question type should be able to have multiple answers, though.

Comment: That's fine, you can have a ManyToMany with just one link - that's why I said "one or more".

Comment: But how does this solve the issue of different types of answers? Once you get down to `AnswerType`, the value is always a `CharField`.

Comment: All answers have the same response - a string, because this is what the user will enter; and the response is stored in `Result`, the actual answer just has a name (for tracking).

Comment: But not all answer types involve entering a string. That's the problem. Some involve selecting checkboxes or radio buttons.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the control is; in the end, all data will be stored as strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57766/discussion-between-pterosaur-and-burhan-khalid).